# method vs __init__ in a python class

Tags: python, class, subprocess

My understanding of these methods are:

- `__init__()` is like constructor.
- `run()` is called when a thread for this class starts.

But why do we need a run method? Could we have instantiated an object of the class and all initializations stay in `__init__()`?

I have gone through [this article](http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2014/06/27/running-a-method-as-a-background-thread-in-python/) , could not make much out of it 
Can you please share some insights on this ?

Comment: In order to distinguish initialization (which happens for any instance) vs code you want to run in a separate thread (which goes into the run method).

Comment: Thanks everyone!! So __init__ is fro initialization and runs in main thread ...where as run method is available through out the life span of child thread.

Comment: No, they're both just methods. __init__ is a 'magic method' for instance initialization. The Python threading module can call your run (but also any other) method when it instantiates a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Python threading module provides a good example.  What if you had a derived thread class that always ran the same function, but perhaps you want to give it different inputs.  You might want to instantiate a lot of objects of the class but with differing inputs -- and you don't want it to start running yet.

Maybe you want to pass this list of instantiated (but not started) threads to some kind of manager that starts and monitors them regardless of what kind of thread they are.

In that case it is good to separate the creation from the run.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` runs once (when the object is constructed), while `run` (in the example you gave) runs in the background (another process) as long as the object exists.

The only difference between `__init__` and `run` are that the first runs in the main thread, while the second runs in another thread.

> But why do we need a run method ? we may have instansiated an object of class and all initializations stay in__init__ ?

In fact, **all inializations are already in __init__.** the `run` method in that example just demonstrates a background thread, and is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about `__init__()` being a constructor. In this example, the goal is to run a function, the `run()` function, in a thread. The example provides a clean way of doing this. You cannot run the code inside the `run()` function inside the `__init__()`, as this would not spawn a new thread.

Consider the case:

```
example = ThreadingExample()
do_something_important_that_doesnt_want_to_wait()
```

This works with the example code.